# ¿Por qué nodejs/express responde con un res.status(400) en el dato que llega por el request?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Desde `Angular` envio los datos a `nodejs`, cuando este los recibe pregunto por el `id_user` si es `null` o `undefined` de la siguiente forma:

```
if(!req.params.id_user){
res.status(400).send('FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO, falta el id_user');
```

}

Lo raro es que desde `Angular` le estoy enviando como `id_user = 1`, por lo que `nodejs` no debería responder con un `res.status(400)`.
Los datos llegan bien porque si quito el `if(!req.paramas.id_user)` la data se guarda perfecto en la base de datos.

Aca desde `nodejs` el `order.controller.ts`

```js
export const createOrder = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {

  if(!req.params.id_user){
    res.status(400).send('FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO, falta el id_user');
  }

  //recibo los datos (de un form, insomnia rest, etc..)
  const { id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date } = (req.body);
  console.log(id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date)

  let idUser = parseInt(id_user);
  let totalPrice = parseInt(total_price);

  const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('INSERT INTO orders (id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)', [idUser, adress, phone_number, totalPrice, provincia, localidad, order_date]);
  return res.json({
    message: 'La orden ah sido creado exitosamente!',
    body: {
      orders: {
        adress
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Aca `Angular`, donde le envio los datos a `nodejs` con el `id_user = 1`

```js
createOrder() {
    this.order.id_user = 1;
    this.order.order_date = this.currentDate;
    this.order.total_price = this.total;
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.order).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('La orden fue creada exitosamente');
        this.createOrderDetail();
      },
      err => console.log('No se pudo crear la orden ' + err)
    );
  }
```

mi servicio `order.service.ts`

```js
createOrder(order: Order){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/orders/create', order);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params` recibe los datos desde la url. Debes hacer un `req.body.id_user`

> ## [req.params](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.params)
>
> Esta propiedad es un objeto que contiene las propiedades mapeadas a la
> ruta llamada "parametros". Por ejemplo, si tienes la ruta
> `/user/:name`, entonces la propidad "name" estará disponible como
> `req.params.name`. El valor por defecto de este objeto es `{}`

En tu servicio no estas mandando ningún parametro por url. Todo lo mandas por el body.

```
createOrder(order: Order){
                           //Orden contiene id_user
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/orders/create', order);
  }
```

> ## [req.body](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#req.body)
>
> Contiene pares de datos clave-valor enviados en el cuerpo de la solicitud. De forma predeterminada, no está definido y se rellena cuando utiliza middleware de análisis corporal como express.json () o express.urlencoded ()

Tu codigo funciona si quitas la linea por que al final estas usando `req.body`:

```
  //En esta linea usas req.body para asignar los datos
  const { id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date } = (req.body);
```

Comment: Gracias @Legna funciona! excelente explicación y muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: :D .. .. . . ..